# Probability of having at least one pair by drawing 4 shoes from 12 pairs.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

There are $12$ pairs of shoes in a cupboard. $4$ are drawn at random. What is the probability that there is at least one pair?

My first attempt: If we chose a pair at first and then draw any two at random from the rest, then there will be at least one pair. 
We can choose one pair in ${12}\choose 4$ ways and chose any $2$ from the rest in ${22}\choose 2$ ways.
Therefore, the required probability= $\frac{{12\choose 4} \times {22\choose 2}}{{24\choose 4}}$ = $\frac{6}{23} =\frac{42}{161}$

But the given answer is $\frac{41}{161}$.

Another attempt: Each of the 4 shoes we choose, will come from one of the pairs. We can choose the four pairs in ${12\choose 4}$ ways and can select a shoe from each of the pairs in $2$ ways so that no pair is obtained. Therefore, required probability =$1-$ $\frac{{12\choose 4} \times 2^4}{{24\choose 4}}$ = $\frac{41}{161}$

What is wrong with the first attempt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to build on Henry's answer, suppose we put the pairs of shoes in order, 1 through 12. By your method, you are over counting picking pair 1 and another pair 11 times. Similarly, you are over counting picking pair 2 with another pair (other than pair 1) 10 times. Continuing on, you are over counting by precisely 11th triangular number, $T_{11} = 66$. Correcting for this,
$$
\frac{12\cdot {22 \choose 2}-66}{24\choose 4} = \frac{41}{161}
$$
as desired.

Comment: Please elaborate more on how the pairs are overcounted. I did not understand why I am "over counting picking pair 1 and another pair 11 times. Similarly, you are over counting picking pair 2 with another pair (other than pair 1) 10 times."

Answer (score 13):

**Calculate $1$ minus the probability of the complementary event:**

The number of ways to choose $4$ out of $24$ shoes is:

- Choose the $1$st shoe out of $24$ shoes
- Choose the $2$nd shoe out of $23$ shoes
- Choose the $3$rd shoe out of $22$ shoes
- Choose the $4$th shoe out of $21$ shoes

The number of ways to choose $4$ out of $24$ shoes with no pairs is:

- Choose the $1$st shoe out of $24$ shoes
- Choose the $2$nd shoe out of $22$ shoes
- Choose the $3$rd shoe out of $20$ shoes
- Choose the $4$th shoe out of $18$ shoes

So the probability of choosing $4$ out of $24$ shoes with at least one pair is:

$$1-\frac{24\cdot22\cdot20\cdot18}{24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21}$$

---

Please note that I've essentially taken into account the order of the shoes.

If I chose **not** to take it into account, then I would need to divide each result by $4!$.

But since this factor appears in both the numerator and the denominator, I can ignore it.

Comment: You could also cancel out the 24's and 22's from the final fraction to simplify it.  Total comes to $1 - 360/483 = 0.2547 = 25.47$%.

Comment: Oh I understand, since taking order into account means we can have the same set of shoes being counted multiple times due to different order of selection. We overcount by 4!

Answer (score 8):

Your first method may double-count the possibility of getting two pairs:  when you "chose any $2$ from the rest in ${22 \choose 2}$ ways", you may be choosing another pair and these two pairs are also counted when chosen in the other order.

In your second method of looking at $1-$ the probability of choosing from different pairs, a similar method is to say that each time you choose a shoe its pair becomes undesirable, making the result $$1-\frac{24}{24}\times \frac{22}{23}\times \frac{20}{22}\times \frac{18}{21} =\frac{41}{161}.$$

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit late.

I was reading Feller's vol 1 chp 4 and got into this question from a very similar exercise.

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Theory-Applications-Edition/dp/0471257087](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471257087)

---

The ways you can do it is of course various, and easiest way to think is to use

`1 - Prob(0 pairs selected)`

and this is just

$$1 - \frac{{12\choose 4} \times 2^4} {{24 \choose 4}}  $$

---

The other way you are considering, of course is correct. This is from inclusion exclusion principle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

The way you calculation is done by:

$$P_1 = S_1 - S_2 + S_3 + - \ldots $$

where $S_1 = \sum_{i=0}^n p_i$, $S_2 = \sum_{i,j=0}^n p_{ij}, \ldots$ and $p_i = P(A_i)$, $p_{ij} = P(A_iA_j),\ldots$

So, in this problem you are looking at:$S_1 = \sum_{}p_i$ where $$p_i = \frac{22\choose 2}{24\choose4}$$ because you are considering 2 slots are already picked, and the rest can go anywhere in the 22 shoes.

And this has ${12\choose 1}$ number of ways happening for your first 2 slots.

Now consider $p_2$. This is calculated as

$$p_2 = \frac{20\choose 0}{24\choose4} $$

This is because, once you set 2 pairs of shoes, you are left with 0 to pick from the rest 20.

And there are ${12\choose2}$ in summation for $p_2$

---

In summary
$$P_1 = S_1 - S_2 = \sum{}p_i - \sum{}p_{ij}=\frac{{12\choose1}\times{22\choose2}-{12\choose2}\times{20\choose0}}{24\choose4}$$

Answer (score 1):

In your first counting method you have two counting stages. In the first one you have $12$ different possible results: $\{P_1, P_2,\ldots,P_{12}\}$, where $P_i$ is a particular pair. In the second stage you would have $\binom{22}{2}$ results for each result or pair of your first stage. That gives you a total of $12\binom{22}{2}$ possible results. Now, let's take a loot a two different results of the first stage, say $P_1$ and $P_9$. For $P_1$ in the first stage, is possible to have $P_9$ as a result in the second stage, and for $P_9$ in the first stage, it is possible to $P_1$ in the second stage, and since the final result $P_1P_9$ is the same as $P_9P_1$, you are effectively counting two times the same result.

Answer (score -1):

To select a pair, the order is irrelevant.
1. Select one shoe
2. Select one shoe - chance this is a pair of first = 1/23 = .04
3. Select one shoe - chance this is a pair of first = 1/22 or chance this is pair of second = 1/21 = 1/22+1/21 = .09
4. Select one shoe - chance this is a pair of first = 1/21 or of second = 1/20, or of third = 1/19 = 1/21+1/20+1/19 = .15
After four selections, probability is .04+.09+.15=.28